# Angular 6 dependent service calls

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular6

I think this question has been asked before, and I tried every single solution I could find but to no avail.
I am a bit new to RxJs so apologies if this seems easy.

Consider the following services:

```
getSessionsByCampaign(campaignDBID: number) : Observable<CfgCampaignGroup[]>{
    return this.http.get<CfgCampaignGroup[]>('http://localhost:4567/api/configuration/sessions?campaign=' + campaignDBID);
}

getDNByDBID(dnDBID: number): Observable<CfgDN[]>{
    return this.http.get<CfgDN[]>('http://localhost:4567/api/configuration/dns?dbid=' + dnDBID);
}
```

I have a component that needs to:

- get the result of getSessionsByCampaign
- then, for each elements returned call getDNByDBID (passing a value from the element)

The closest I got was to do:

```
this._configurationService.getSessionsByCampaign(this.campaignDBID).subscribe(dialingSessionsList => {
  this.dialingSessions = dialingSessionsList;
   dialingSessionsList.forEach((e) => {
    this._configurationService.getDNByDBID(e["CfgCampaignGroup"].origDNDBID.value).subscribe(dn => this.dns.push(dn[0]));
  }) 
});
```

But obviously, when I try to consume this.dns in my component template, it is undefined...

I have looked at mergeMap, switchMap and forkJoin but can't adapt them to my particular situation (the fact that the first call returns an array and that I need to make the second call for each element of the array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (since you used the "angular6" tag, I'm assuming rxjs 6):

```
this._configurationService.getSessionsByCampaign(this.campaignDBID).pipe(
    mergeMap(sessionsArray => from(sessionsArray)),
    mergeMap(session => 
       this._configurationService.getDNByDBID(session.origDNDBID.value)
    )
)
```

So, first, the getSessionsByCampaign function is called, which returns an Observable of an array of sessions. We pipe that observable through two mergeMap operators:

The first mergeMap invokes the 'from' operator, which turns the Observable of array to an array of Observables.

The second mergeMap invokes the getDNByDBID function on the value of each of the Observables in the array.

This will emit each of the results in turn.

If you want to emit a single observable with an array of the results, add toArray() to the end of the pipe, as in:

```
this._configurationService.getSessionsByCampaign(this.campaignDBID).pipe(
    mergeMap(sessionsArray => from(sessionsArray)),
    mergeMap(session => 
       this._configurationService.getDNByDBID(session.origDNDBID.value)
    ),
    toArray()
)
```

Your imports will be:

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
import {mergeMap, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Edit: It would look like this with the subscription:

```
this._configurationService.getSessionsByCampaign(this.campaignDBID).pipe(
    mergeMap(sessionsArray => from(sessionsArray)),
    mergeMap(session => 
       this._configurationService.getDNByDBID(session.origDNDBID.value)
    ),
    toArray()
).subscribe(
    dnArray => this.dns = dnArray,
    err => this.console.error(err); // or other, better error-handling
)
```

Comment: Thanks @GreyBeardedGeek. While I do understand the explanation (and you just made map cleared to me), how do I consume the resulting Observable in my template?